# Android BroadcastReceiver not working by clicking at notification action

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

I'm building a music player app and I have a problem with the notification part I think all of my code about the notification is right but when I tap at notification controller buttons broadcast receiver don't work.

### AndroidManifest:

```html
<receiver android:name=".notification.NotificationController">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ydp.eight_d_musicplayer.ACTION_NOTIFY_PLAY_PAUSE"/>
                <action android:name="com.ydp.eight_d_musicplayer.ACTION_NOTIFY_SKIP_NEXT"/>
                <action android:name="com.ydp.eight_d_musicplayer.ACTION_NOTIFY_SKIP_PREVIOUS"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
```

### My Broadcast:

```js
public class NotificationController extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String ACTION_NOTIFY_PLAY_PAUSE = "com.ydp.eight_d_musicplayer.ACTION_NOTIFY_PLAY_PAUSE";
    public static String ACTION_NOTIFY_SKIP_NEXT = "com.ydp.eight_d_musicplayer.ACTION_NOTIFY_SKIP_NEXT";
    public static String ACTION_NOTIFY_SKIP_PREVIOUS = "com.ydp.eight_d_musicplayer.ACTION_NOTIFY_SKIP_PREVIOUS";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_NOTIFY_PLAY_PAUSE)){
            if (Player.player.isPlaying()){
                Player.player.pause();
            }else {
                Player.player.start();
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_NOTIFY_SKIP_PREVIOUS)){
            Toast.makeText(context, "previous", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

### And My Service:

```js
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this, MainActivity.class),0);
        Intent previous = new Intent();
        previous.setAction(ACTION_NOTIFY_SKIP_PREVIOUS);
        Intent play = new Intent();
        play.setAction(ACTION_NOTIFY_PLAY_PAUSE);
        Intent next = new Intent();
        play.setAction(ACTION_NOTIFY_SKIP_NEXT);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "playback")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.music_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE))
                    .setContentText(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM) + " . " + retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST))
                    .setLargeIcon(songCover)
                    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_previous_black_24dp,"previous",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,11,previous,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp,"play",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,12,play,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_next_black_24dp,"next",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,13,next,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            Notification.MediaStyle mediaStyle = new Notification.MediaStyle();
            mediaStyle.setBuilder(notification);
            startForeground(1, mediaStyle.build());
        }
```

**Help, please!**

Comment: You need to use explicit `Intent`s for all of them: `new Intent(this, NotificationController.class)`.

Comment: i got same issue, have u solved?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `Intent`s like this:

```java
new Intent(this, NameOfTheClass.class);
```

In cases where you are in coroutine for example use

```
applicationContext
```